# remove a char from string or replace it by another in string array

Tags: c#, arrays

we have an array of string like this:

```
string[] names = new [] {"Jo!oje","kaba!b","!zorrat","kotlet!","fat!!"};
```

and want to remove `'!'` from each string. how can do it?

Comment: Ideally share with us what you've attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = names.Select(x => x.Replace("!", "")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ehsan had no problems?

Comment: There is no good reason to provide half broken answer even if OP somehow gets enough info from it. Such code is perfect for comment, but... See the other answer copy-pasted bad code too spreading mistakes. I'd fix your answer but touching code in the answer is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks mate, didn't have a C# compiler handy!

Comment: Thanks. Note that you don't need to `Cast`... And there are always http://ideone.com to quickly test your code..

Comment: @Luke: Dear Luke I check it and wrote my answer just 2 min after your answer. It worked correct. Thank you so much for quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
string[] names = new [] {"Jo!oje","kaba!b","!zorrat","kotlet!","fat!!"};
var result = names.Select(x => x.Replace("!", ""));
```

Comment: If providing identical answer consider fixing compile errors and actually make it correct to match OP request.

Comment: @EhsanDavoudiEhs Update your code, sorry for that mistake.

Comment: In my opinion it don't need to use `'var'` for it. and we can use this code: `names = names.Select(x => x.Replace("!", "")).ToArray;`

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi yes, but i want the code is more clearly so i edited

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do replace the char in the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < names.Length; i++) names[i] = names[i].Replace("!", string.Empty);
```

I personally prefer the LINQ version though.

Comment: At least this one compiles, though!